# Select DIV Contain Specific text

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I try to get div with specific text, but its give me wrong result.

this my html:

```
<div class="ui-droppable">
  <div class="numb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">1</div>
  <div class="numb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">10</div>
  <div class="numb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">7</div>
  <div class="numb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle bred">6</div>
</div>
```

this my jquery:

```
$('.ui-droppable').find("div.numb.ui-draggable:contains('1')").addClass('cont');
```

if I run my jquery, it will adding class to div with contain 1 and 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For exact content match use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method. Although [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method is unnecessary here combine them into a single selector.

```
$(".ui-droppable div.numb.ui-draggable:contains('1')").filter(function(){
  return $(this).text().trim() == '1' ; 
}).addClass('cont');
```

```js
$(".ui-droppable div.numb.ui-draggable:contains('1')").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() == '1';
}).addClass('cont');
```

```css
.cont {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-droppable">
  <div class="numb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">1</div>
  <div class="numb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">10</div>
  <div class="numb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">7</div>
  <div class="numb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle bred">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DennySutedja :  glad to help you :)

Comment: both of you give me a right answer, but i have to choose.

Comment: @DennySutedja : accept answer which fulfills your needs

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach better, simpler and memory efficient

```
$( ".ui-draggable-handle" ).each(function() {
    if($(this).html() == "1"){
        $(this).addClass('cont');
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: both of you give me a right answer, but i have to choose.